# tan(x) approximation to double precision on |x| < pi/4

Tags: c, optimization, trigonometry, numeric, numerical-methods

I want to approximate tan(x) quickly to within 1 ULP on the range -pi/4 to pi/4. I have found a solution that is almost good enough but the last factor of two eludes me even with considerable computing time and simulated annealing.

I seek a particular numerical approximation of tan(x) which takes the form:

tan(x) = x*P(x^2)/Q(x^2)

Where both P and Q are both cubics in x^2. I need to impose a few additional constraints on the approximation. Namely to match the function value and gradient at zero and ideally at pi/4 too. I have settled for the moment on relaxing the gradient constraint at pi/4. I should say here that the approximation I seek is ominously missing from Hart's "Bible" of Computer Approximations which suggests that it is a rather tricky one to converge.

Normally he gives the entire sequence but the table for tan & pi/4 skips 3,3 which is odd because it should be perfect for 64 bit reals. Precision is the number of correct decimal digits obtained with N,M the highest non-zero coefficients in P, Q respectively

| Precision | N | M | Index |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10.66 | 2 | 2 | 4283 |
| 13.62 | 2 | 3 | 4284 |
| 19.74 | 4 | 3 | 4285 |
| 19.94 | 3 | 4 | 4286 |

The coefficients that I have were derived from the Pade approximation by simulated annealing and a bit of native cunning perturbing the solution out of local minima. It is OK but it still isn't quite good enough for my purposes. There is a recalcitrant patch ~0.14 where the relative error spikes remain at 5.5e-16 (about 60 per billion test cases) and slightly too many values in the 4.4e-16 bins as well. This is the relative error histogram of what I have so far on a 10^9 random challenge test:

```
-5.5511e-16 | 0
-4.4409e-16 | 704272
-3.3307e-16 | 0
-2.2204e-16 | 157067630
-1.1102e-16 | 0
 0.0000e+00 | 485332167
 1.1102e-16 | 240168741
 2.2204e-16 | 99172390
 3.3307e-16 | 16874505
 4.4409e-16 | 680236
 5.5511e-16 | 59
 6.6613e-16 | 0

 Mean  1.94185e-17   StdDev  1.31764e-16   Entropy 1.29231
```

Entropy is a quick figure of merit for comparing the histogram distribution. It would be zero for a perfect solution with all values in one bin.

The coefficients for the various approximations are as follows

| Pade | 0 (1) | 1 (x^2) | 2 (x^4) | 3 (x^6) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Pn | 135135 | -17325 | 378 | -1 |
| Qn | 135135 | -62370 | 3150 | 28 |

The parent Pade approximation maximum relative error is 1.34e-4 at pi/4.

Remez with decimal coefficients is good to 5.5e-16 - good enough for a quick look see and will work OK in Excel spreadsheets but is inexact due to decimal rounding.

| Remez | 0 (1) | 1 (x^2) | 2 (x^4) | 3 (x^6) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Pn | 133506.920100216 | -17127.5484486707 | 374.700589646508 | -1 |
| Qn | 133506.920100216 | -61629.8551487417 | 3117.06295917985 | -27.8423369154197 |

Remez full accuracy hexadecimal coded floating point representation  (my best so far)

| Remez* | 0 (1) | 1 (x^2) | 2 (x^4) | 3 (x^6) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Pn | 0x1.04c175c5d80a5p+17 | -0x1.0b9e319c87430p+14 | 0x1.76b359d7d3ac0p+8 | -1 |
| Qn | 0x1.04c175c5d80a5p+17 | -0x1.e17bb5d60e518p+15 | 0x1.85a203c2f84f8p+11 | -0x1.bd7a3645ff105p+4 |

For specific reasons I need to keep P0=Q0 so that for very small values x == tan(x). I'd also like to keep one of the x^6 term coefficients at 1.0 (saves a multiply) but if something has to give to get to 16 good decimal digits then that is it.

This is a sample implementation (using the shorter slightly less accurate decimal values). Upgraded to an MRE 24/11/23.

```
// Toy_Pade.cpp : Demonstrates the failing cases err>5.5e-16 and prints out failures
//
#define _USE_MATH_DEFINES
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

double TanPQ(double x)
{
  const double P[4] = { 133506.920100216, -17127.548448670765,  374.700589646508, -1.0 };
  const double Q[4] = { 133506.920100216, -61629.8551487418,    3117.06295917985, -27.84233691541965 };

  double sumP, sumQ, x2;
  int i;
  sumP = sumQ = 0;
  x2 = x * x;
  for (i = 3; i >= 0; i--)
  {
     sumP = sumP * x2 + P[i];
     sumQ = sumQ * x2 + Q[i];
  }
  return x * sumP / sumQ;
}

double tan87_diff(double x)
// return x86 fptan x forced to the x87 coprocessor or tanl()
{
  long double y,t;
  if (x == 0) return 0;
  t = TanPQ(x);
  #ifdef _M_IX86
  _asm {
         fld qword ptr[x]
         fptan
         fxch st(1)  // save the 1
         fdivr qword ptr[t]
         fsubp st(1), st
         fstp qword ptr[y]
   }
  #else
  y = 1 - t / tanl(x);
 #endif
 return y;
}

int main()
{
  double x, dx, err;
  dx = M_PI / 2000000000;
  x = 0;
  while (x < M_PI / 4)
  {
     err = tan87_diff(x);
     if (fabs(err) > 5.0e-16) printf("%-26.18g %22.14a %g\n", x, x, err);
     x = x + dx;
  }
}
```

What makes optimisation so difficult is that at the final stage there is a smooth function but with a sparse bed of sharp nails sticking up from it so there are zillions of local optima all of them much of a muchness and a very few good ones. The cryptographic LLL method is supposed to be able to resolve this conundrum but that is beyond my programming ability to do from scratch. The problem boils down to finding a set of mantissa values whose ratios have for want of a better word "magic" properties making their ratios more exact than any single coefficient.

If anyone has access to the Intel LLL optimisation package, Sollya or ARM's Remez package or can find a slightly better approximation I would be very interested. I have tried and failed to do better with ARM's code and Sollya myself. It is frustratingly close to the required precision now but falls just short of where I need it to be. I'd also be interested in any suggestions for other heuristic tweaks that I might try. I have a few ideas about that.

Comment: What are you using as the 'true' value? Are you using tanl()? Have you checked the assembler is using 80 bit long doubles? If it's using 64 bit, you're probably suffering from noise which will hamper convergence.

Comment: @SimonGoater Effectively tanl(). I'm using assembler and 80 bit FP x87 hardware values for tan(x) as a reference and the differences computed in x87 80 bit arithmetic too but rounded down to 64 bits for display.  I know that isn't really good enough which is why I have been trying to figure out Sollya and ARM's Remez code. It is all a bit marginal. I could also accumulate the summed errors in 80 bit precision (but don't at present). That is an oversight on my part. I could ultimately switch to quad precision reference tan and see if that helps (it will certainly be much slower).

Comment: I think to hope to get 16 digits of precision, you may need 80 bit arithmetic and coefficients throughout.

Comment: @MartinBrown Aside, rather than 15 significant decimal digits, use 17 or the hex.  Assuming the hex constants are best, the decimal introduce unnecessary error. `d = 133506.920100216; printf("%.17g %a\n", d,d);` --> `133506.920100216 0x1.04c175c5d8086p+17` which differs from `0x1.04c175c5d80a5p+17`.

Comment: @MartinBrown what are some of the `x` values when the relative error is extreme?

Comment: It is not clear what you want is possible. Even if you have ideal polynomials P and Q, you are computing them with `double` arithmetic, so the best that `sumP` and `sumQ` can be is correctly rounded. They will each have rounding errors averaging around a ¼ ULP or more and ranging up to nearly ½ ULP at places. Then you divide those and multiplying by `x`, producing more rounding errors. It seems unlikely there will not be errors over 1 ULP at points in the domain no matter what coefficients are used for P and Q. Do you plan to do the computations with some form of extended precision?

Comment: @chux I have modified the question to include a toy MRE. I see 23 failures on MSC x86 and Intel compilers and all of them on the same values. I haven't tested it on GCC yet. The rounded decimal values are more portable - you can mock it up in a spreadsheet with those coefficients and still have very acceptable accuracy. There are a lot more on MSC with x64 since it does not honour the long double type or provide a proper tanl(). It is exquisitely sensitive to tiny changes! First fail is at 0.124401880709456542  0x1.fd8cd393540160p-4 and last at 0.137501657624323564  0x1.199a7815235890p-3

Comment: @ericpostpschil I agree that it is very marginal but I have hopes that the LLL algorithm might just tip the balance. I'd like rid of the 5.5e-16 spikes entirely. It has to be computed in double precision coefficients or it won't be fast enough. Running my own optimiser in long double might make it easier to get a better solution in double precision as suggested by Simon Goater. I overlooked that possibility through being fixated on the coefficients and implementation having to be 64 bit doubles.

Comment: @njuffa there is a hidden reason for wanting it as a rational approximation that is cubic in x^2 in that one of the intended uses is in a semi-analytic method for solving a more complex problem on the domain -pi/2 to pi/2 and avoiding a (slow) division. I'm relying on FMA to keep it close enough when evaluated numerically. The whole equation to be solved is multiplied through by the denominator (or numerator if pi/4 < x <=pi/2) to give a cubic or quartic in x^2 (for which analytic solutions exist).

Comment: What is the literature that says the Lenstra–Lenstra–Lovász lattice basis reduction algorithm can be used to reduce the maximum errors in this sort of numerical approximation?

Comment: @EricPostpishil I first saw it mentioned in "A Handbook of Floating Point Arithmetic" (p393, p442-450). They cite various 2007-8 papers by Brisebarre & Muller and this Tex paper [FP Accuracy Nasty Values](https://people.inf.ethz.ch/gonnet/FPAccuracy/NastyValues) by Gonnet at ETH (which I haven't yet read - only just found it trying to answer your question). Additional serendipitous find there [FP Accuracy Analysis](https://people.inf.ethz.ch/gonnet/FPAccuracy/Analysis.html). I'm right at the limits of my own understanding here so I may have got the wrong end of the stick...

Comment: @EricPostpischil sorry I mis-spelt your handle somehow please see earlier message re LLL

Comment: @MartinBrown  As the goal here is a low ULP error for `tan_in_primary_range()`, I wonder why just the primary range?  More common `tan()` goal is a much wider range.  If so, the _range reduction_ used contributes its errors too which may swamp out our efforts here.  Perhaps some hints to the larger use case?

Comment: @chux I have absolute control of the range of inputs to this code. It will never see an argument outside of +/-pi/2. My other option if I absolutely have to is to take the approximation range down to pi/8 and use another if statement to divide the range 0-pi into 3 segments rather than <pi/4 and >pi/4 as it is at present. I may still try that just in case it turns out to be faster. I'm wary of having two comparisons so close together as it may cause a pipeline stall.

Comment: @MartinBrown Is using `fma()` a possibility for the solution?

Answer (score 6):

TL;DR A faithfully-rounded approximation to tan(x) on [-π/4, π/4] that also satisfies all the other constraints mentioned by asker seems impossible.

In 1934 the Soviet mathematician E. Remez published a straightforward numerical algorithm for computing the coefficients of the minimax polynomial approximation of chosen degree to a function <sup>[1,2]</sup>. This algorithm was subsequently extended by various authors for use with rational approximations, with work basically complete by the early 1980s. The "engine" of the Remez algorithm is the solving of a system of linear equations. At the conceptual level, this occurs with infinite precision, delivering infinitely precise coefficients. In practical terms one typically uses an arbitrary precision library. For example, in my own work I usually work with a precision of 1000 bits. Even so, cases of extreme ill-conditioning, degenerate solutions, and slow convergence can occur once one moves beyond simple elementary functions.

Using the results of the Remez algorithm with *finite-precision* computation immediately creates problems. The simple act of rounding the computed coefficients to the closest working-precision representation destroys the minimax property, sometimes severely so. In the early 2000s researchers made efforts to fix this by observing that for a *machine-efficient* approximation we are basically looking for the solution closest to the Remez solution in a *discrete lattice*. They added a heuristic search that searches the lattice as a post-processing step to the foundational Remez algorithm. This works well for polynomial approximations (the solutions found typically largely restore the minimax property) and is readily available to the computing public via the `fpminimax` command of the open-source [Sollya tool](https://www.sollya.org/). I am not aware of a readily available solution for rational approximations, but haven't looked at Sollya in almost a decade.

However, even when selecting the best machine-precision coefficients we still have not taken into consideration that the evaluation of the approximation also happens with finite precision. Since 2014 I have experimented with a heuristic search based on simulated annealing to address this, with often favorable results for *single-precision* approximations. As for the literature, I have come across some initial exploration of, but no definite solutions to, this issue.

All other parts of a function approximation being equal, rational approximations have a significant drawback compared to polynomial approximations: Rather than dealing with the accumulated round-off error from one polynomial, they accumulate round-off error from *two* polynomials plus a division. In my experience, an approximation of the form x*P(x<sup>2</sup>)/Q(x<sup>2</sup>), where P and Q are polynomials, therefore has a maximum error of no less than 2.5 ulps. Common ways to get around this is to perform intermediate computations using an extended-precision data type or the local use of quasi-extended precision techniques, as is often done in [FDLIBM](https://www.netlib.org/fdlibm/k_tan.c). Some relief can be achieved by the following algebraic transformation:

```
       (a x² + b) x² + c               (((a+d) x² + (b+e)) x² + (c+f)) x² + g
x + x³ --------------------------  = x --------------------------------------
       ((d x² + e) x² + f) x² + g      ((d x² + e) x² + f) x² + g
```

The left-hand side here is called a rational approximation in Cody-Waite form, after the two authors who popularized it, although to the best of my knowledge it was pioneered by H. Kuki in the 1960s. This is an application of a general design principle in finite-precision floating-point computations, that if we are to compute f(x) ≈ x, we should compute it as f(x) = x + g(x), because as long as |g(x)| < |x|/2, the accumulated error in the computation of g(x) will be (partially) eliminated during the alignment step of the addition.

So for numerical evaluation of an approximation to tan(x) one could use the left-hand side, while using the right-hand side for any additional analytical work desired. Performing a simple test based on a large number of random test vectors using coefficients from the Remez algorithm, one immediately observes a definite accuracy advantage with the Cody-Waite arrangement:

```c
/* Compute tan(a) on [-PI/4, PI/4]. When testing with 1B random test vectors
   the largest error observed was 2.87100 ulps @ 0.77010979666149337
*/
double my_tan_rat (double a)
{
    double s, p, q, r;
    s = a * a;
    p =            -7.4836345662662022e-6;  // -0x1.f637dce500dc1p-18
    p = fma (p, s,  2.8059181997587578e-3); //  0x1.6fc6fdce72345p-9
    p = fma (p, s, -1.2828347003779111e-1); // -0x1.06b97be3700b2p-3
    p = fma (p, s,  1.0000000000000000e+0); //  0x1.0000000000000p+0
    q =            -2.0844803827815942e-4;  // -0x1.b525b03bf7426p-13
    q = fma (q, s,  2.3344852656729746e-2); //  0x1.7e7b68ac32acep-6
    q = fma (q, s, -4.6161680337112165e-1); // -0x1.d8b213470d57cp-2
    q = fma (q, s,  1.0000000000000000e+0); //  0x1.0000000000000p+0
    r = (p / q) * a;
    return r;
}

/* Compute tan(a) on [-PI/4, PI/4]. When testing with 1B random test vectors
   the largest error observed was 1.34290 ulps @ 0.78339986284646490
*/
double my_tan_rat_cw (double a)
{
    double s, p, q, r;
    s = a * a;
    p =             6.0284853818520106e-4;  //  0x1.3c10f60c2ddc2p-11
    p = fma (p, s, -6.1615805421222844e-2); // -0x1.f8c1b5a66d606p-5
    p = fma (p, s,  1.0000000000000000e+0); //  0x1.0000000000000p+0
    q =            -6.2529620840320529e-4;  // -0x1.47d5d61f8c6e0p-11
    q = fma (q, s,  7.0033226411156085e-2); //  0x1.1edb29111bc42p-4
    q = fma (q, s, -1.3848474162642035e+0); // -0x1.62855c3ace0adp+0
    q = fma (q, s,  3.0000000000000178e+0); //  0x1.8000000000028p+1
    r = fma (p / q, s * a, a);
    return r;
}
```

Obviously polynomial approximations can also numerically benefit from the Cody-Waite form, in addition to the natural numerical advantage relatively to rational approximations outlined above:

```c
/* Compute tan(a) on [-PI/4, PI/4]. When testing with 1B random test vectors
   the largest error observed was 1.05526 ulps @ 0.76793732843110962
*/
double my_tan_poly_cw (double a)
{
    double s, p, r;
    s = a * a;
    p =             2.0850971295515380e-5;  //  0x1.5dd23d63ccbc5p-16
    p = fma (p, s, -4.4825533934459124e-5); // -0x1.780619e41f4f2p-15 
    p = fma (p, s,  8.9357886641150614e-5); //  0x1.76cb4cd94ecdcp-14
    p = fma (p, s, -2.6283376221898116e-5); // -0x1.b8f63dc5efa9ap-16
    p = fma (p, s,  1.3645248966085008e-4); //  0x1.1e295f60acc30p-13
    p = fma (p, s,  2.2241542416199695e-4); //  0x1.d2705f2202d73p-13
    p = fma (p, s,  5.9505257333405601e-4); //  0x1.37fa9abc268e0p-11
    p = fma (p, s,  1.4547608886063121e-3); //  0x1.7d5b59c2a023cp-10
    p = fma (p, s,  3.5922885929182500e-3); //  0x1.d6d9340c7b3d4p-9
    p = fma (p, s,  8.8632192186201136e-3); //  0x1.226e125733448p-7
    p = fma (p, s,  2.1869489605109288e-2); //  0x1.664f49a896048p-6
    p = fma (p, s,  5.3968253926831522e-2); //  0x1.ba1ba1b46a358p-5
    p = fma (p, s,  1.3333333333414271e-1); //  0x1.11111111182fap-3
    p = fma (p, s,  3.3333333333332782e-1); //  0x1.55555555554f2p-2
    r = fma (p, s * a, a);
    return r;
}
```

Please keep in mind that even using a large number of random test vectors can not provide rigorous error bounds, but it can provide a reasonable idea about the relative accuracy of various approximation approaches.

While establishing exact error bounds is easily possible for single-argument single-precision functions by exhaustive test, this is a much more difficult undertaking when using double precision. Error bounds can be rigorously established by (mechanically checked) mathematical proof, but to derive *tight* upper bounds can take a specialized mathematician weeks. In the absence of mathematical proof, various heuristics such as directed random searches could be used to increase confidence in accuracy measurements, e.g. re-centering the search interval on the location of the maximum error found so far every *n* test vectors, while shrinking the interval width gradually with increasing *n*.

---

<sup>1</sup> E. Remes, "Sur un procédé convergent d'approximations successives pour déterminer les polynomes d'approximation", *Comptes rendus hebdomadaires des séances de l'Académie des sciences*, **198**, Jan.-Jun.1934, [pp. 2063-2065](https://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k31506/f2063.item.r=Remes) (presented at the session of June 4, 1934).

<sup>2</sup> Eugène Remes, "Sur le calcul effectif des polynomes d'approximation de Tchebichef,"*Comptes rendus hebdomadaires des séances de l'Académie des sciences*, **199**, Jul.-Dec.1934, [pp. 337-340](https://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k3151h/f337.image.r=Remes) (presented at the session of July 23, 1934).

Comment: "maximum error: 1.07 ulp" --> what x value was that?  Try `x = 0.78100684512866114`, I get ULP error of 1.26.  Trying to discern if we are determining ULP in a like fashion.

Comment: Maybe some exhaustive search on a narrow (low precision) format would be feasible and would suggest what is possible.

Comment: @njuffa Putting the expression into Cody-Waite form was extremely useful almost halving the error. I'll summarise my results of various (slow) numerical simulations in a not-quite an answer since they would be too long to fit in a comment. I am getting closer but I am now fairly convinced that I will have to settle for slightly higher errors. There are two distinct problems the numerical one and the behind the scenes algebraic one where I want it as x * ratio of two cubics. You suggestion goes a long way to solving the numerical one. BTW which Remez tool did you use to get the approx?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256077/discussion-between-chux-reinstate-monica-and-njuffa).

Answer (score 5):

> I want to approximate tan(x) quickly to within 1 ULP on the range -pi/4 to pi/4.

Without additional precision with wider types or via `fma()`, <strike>I do not see this as happening.

It may not be possible.</strike> is challenging. See  below:

An alterative uses one more `q[]` term:

```
double tan_alt(double x) {
  double g = x*x;
  static const double p[4] = { 1.0, -0.13338350006421960681e0, 0.34248878235890589960e-2, -0.17861707342254426711e-4 };
  static const double q[5] = { 1.0, -0.46671683339755294240e0, 0.25663832289440112864e-1, -0.31181531907010027307e-3, 0.49819433993786512270e-6 };
  double xnum = ((p[3]*g + p[2])*g + p[1])*g*x + x;
  double xden = (((q[4]*g + q[3])*g + q[2])*g + q[1])*g + 1;
  return  xnum/xden;
}
```

Improved random testing has a worst case of < 2.7 ULP error.
This is a tad better than OP's 4.1 ULP error.
Still not within OP's goal of <= 1.0 ULP.

By OP's relative error measure of 5.0e-16, the error here was less than 3.4e-16.

---

Another set with 4 `p[]`, 4 `q[]` terms:

```
double tan_alt4x4(double x) {
  double g = x * x;
  static const double p[4] = {1.0, -0.1282834704095743847e+0, //
      +0.2805918241169988906e-2, -0.7483634966612065149e-5};
  static const double q[4] = {1.0, -0.4616168037429048840e+0, //
      +0.2334485282206872802e-1, -0.2084480442203870948e-3};
  double xnum = ((p[3] * g + p[2]) * g + p[1]) * g * x + x; // f*P(g)
  double xden = ((q[3] * g + q[2]) * g + q[1]) * g + 1; // Q(g)
  return xnum / xden;
}
```

Worst case found: better than 3.0 ULP

---

**Comparing to C library `tan(x)` to `tanl(x)`**

Rather than `t = TanPQ(x);`, I tried `t = tan(x);` and came up with a max relative error (per OP's code) of `-1.35525e-16`.  By my ULP test, a sample worst case found was < 0.84 at x:+0.66050441268436411.

Following compares invalidated due to a broken `fma()` in my C library.

<strike>**Comparing to [@njuffa](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77546905/2410359) `my_tan_poly_cw()` to `tanl(x)`**</strike>

**Comparing to [@njuffa](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77546905/2410359) `my_tan_rat_cw()` to `tanl(x)`**

---

---

**2nd effort**

> I want to approximate tan(x) quickly to within 1 ULP on the range -pi/4 to pi/4.

Let us step back to basics.

Mathematically: If we use the [Taylor's series for `tan()`](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=taylor+series+tan+x), we need quite a few terms for `x` near π/4 to reach a error less than 1 part in 2<sup>53</sup>.

A direct C implementation follows.  It does not use any extended precision math nor `fma()`.

My deep test (10<sup>9</sup> values in the [0.7 π/4]) netted a worst case at:

```
tan(x:0.78318202430135764) -->
 ref:0x1.fdbc560aa0a813d6p-1,
   f:0x1.fdbc560aa0a80p-1 --> 1.24 ulp
```

Deeper testing may yield a worse [ULP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_in_the_last_place).  I expect still less than 1.3 ULP.  OP's goal is <= 1.0 ULP.

Below `x = 0.7`, the ULP error was always less than 1.0.

**Candidate improvements**

- Using `psum[1] = pow(x, 3) * tan_coeff[1];` after the first loop alone improved worst case ULP to 1.064.
- Using an extended precision `long double sum` in the 2nd loop improved worst case ULP to 1.071.  We alternative could use other tricks to achieve a wider sum calculation.
- Using both improved worst case ULP to 0.904.
- Since ULP under 1.0 is easy below 0.7, code could vector at this level, using faster few terms when `|x|` is smaller than some threshold near 0.7.
- The [holy grail](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Holy_Grail#Noun) is using a lower degree polynomial that is customized to best approximate `tan()`.  There exist many such reduced sets as answered above here as well as in other good answers.

```
// https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=taylor+tanx
static const double tan_coeff[] = { //
    1,                      // (1 x)
    0.33333333333333333,    // (1 x^3)/3
    0.13333333333333333,    // (2 x^5)/15
    0.053968253968253968,   // (17 x^7)/315
    0.021869488536155203,   // (62 x^9)/2835
    0.0088632355299021966,  // (1382 x^11)/155925
    0.0035921280365724810,  // (21844 x^13)/6081075
    0.0014558343870513183,  // (929569 x^15)/638512875
    0.00059002744094558598, // (6404582 x^17)/10854718875
    0.00023912911424355248, // (443861162 x^19)/1856156927625
    9.6915379569294503e-05, // (18888466084 x^21)/194896477400625
    3.9278323883316834e-05, // (113927491862 x^23)/2900518163668125
    1.5918905069328965e-05, // (58870668456604 x^25)/3698160658676859375
    6.4516892156554308e-06, // (8374643517010684 x^27)/1298054391195577640625
    2.6147711512907546e-06, // (689005380505609448 x^29)/263505041412702261046875
    1.0597268320104654e-06, // (129848163681107301953 x^31)/122529844256906551386796875
    4.2949110782738059e-07, // (1736640792209901647222 x^33)/4043484860477916195764296875
    1.7406618963571648e-07, //
    7.0546369464009683e-08, //
    2.8591366623052539e-08, //
    1.1587644432798852e-08, //
    4.6962953982309016e-09, //
    1.9033368339312759e-09, //
    7.7139336353590623e-10, //
    3.1263395458920870e-10, //
    1.2670576930305401e-10, //
    5.1351914080393677e-11, //
    2.0812146867700474e-11, //
    8.43484541909434E-12, //
    3.41851408681116E-12, //
    1.38547157429485E-12,
};
```

```
#define tan_coeff_N (sizeof tan_coeff / sizeof tan_coeff[0])

double my_tan(double x) {
  double xx = x*x;
  double xpower = x;
  double psum[tan_coeff_N];
  for (size_t i = 0; i < tan_coeff_N; i++) {
    psum[i] = xpower * tan_coeff[i];
    xpower *= xx;
  }

  // Summing from smallest to greatest improves results by about 4 ULP!
  double sum = 0.0;
  for (int i = tan_coeff_N; i-- > 0; ) {
    sum += psum[i];
  }
  return sum;
}
```

---

**Candidate success with 3rd effort**

In the range `x`:[0.66 ... pi/4], code can use a different series to determine `tan(x)`.

The overall *tested* error is < 0.88 ULP over the [0...pi/4] range.

The coefficients were determined by using the Taylor's series  offsetting `x` by 0.75.  As this incurs even power-of-`x`, we need minor additional code (not shown) to handle negative `x`.

```
  if (fabs(x) > 0.66) {
    if (x < 0) TBD_Code();
    size_t n = sizeof tan_coefficient0_75 / sizeof tan_coefficient0_75[0];
    x -= 0.75;
    double xpower = 1.0;
    double psum[n];
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++) {
      psum[i] = xpower * tan_coefficient0_75[i];
      xpower *= x;
    }
    double sum = 0.0;
    for (int i = n; i-- > 0;) {
      sum += psum[i];
    }
    return sum;
  }
```

```
const double tan_coefficient0_75[] = { //
    0.931596459944072461268, 1.86787196418032780561, 1.74010290945917470346,
        2.24369769845065726317, 2.6702551362143535352, 3.27700773073232846282,
        3.9816028001079171463, 4.85539610076066983305, 5.91349251297151975179,
        7.20542033530190947346, 8.77820791936091077319, 10.6949021456344782162,
        13.0298422350220210924, 15.8746642588110872894, 19.3405519036669012959,
        23.5631614135143484107, 28.7076814530237660623, 34.97540286557598882};
```

This meets OP's goal without higher precision math.

Comment: Re “By random testing, it has a worst case of < 2.6 ULP error”: Is 2.6 ULP the worst case that random testing actually found, or is it a projection from the errors that the random testing did find? Figuring out what error exists but that you did not see may be akin to the [German tank problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/German_tank_problem), albeit with a trickier probability distribution.

Comment: @EricPostpischil True that is a good concern,  Yet good testing takes time (IMO, much more time/effort than the `tan_alt()`). FWIW, it is a billion random values in the `double` range +/-pi/4.  The salient point is that the _same_ approach was used to find the worst case for this alternative and OP's and resulted in a better 2.6 vs 3.9.  Perhaps deeper testing will reveal worst ULP errors, but I am disinclined to think that the proportion of 2.6:3.9 will change much.  Perhaps more later.

Comment: @EricPostpischil, Sample wort case: x:+0.78536049660000373,+0x1.921ac560ef469p-1 y(high precision):+0x1.fff62051b87eba82p-1 y(tan_alt):+0x1.fff62051b87e9p-1 diff:-2.65674 ulp

Comment: @chux I went back to Hart's tables to generate an optimum 3,4 polynomial TAN4286 and combined it with C-W evaluation in 64bit FP as suggested by njuffa. The results are quite encouraging although my target accuracy seems unattainable in 64bit FP the various tricks suggested here have helped me a lot. Thanks!

Comment: @MartinBrown Did you find this answer meet the goal of < 1.0 ULP?  It did for me.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't quite a complete answer to my question but summarises the progress that I have made thanks to the various inputs from Eric, @njuffa, @chux and others above.

My first try was to task my optimiser with reducing the count in the 5.5e-16 bin. This got it down from 60ppb to 2ppb (rather slowly since each test requires 10^9 evaluations of the function). This also made the distribution more symmetrical and reduced the mean by an order of magnitude but the variance went up to 1.38e-16 even thought the number of outliers was reduced.

Chux's suggestion of add another term caused me to revisit the Hart tables and implement the same 3,4 structure which Hart claims is good for 19.94 decimal digits if computed with appropriate precision. Unfortunately Hart's tables are all scaled so that their argument is on 0-1 ie as fractions of pi/4. This means that terms of order N have a systematic error *(pi_64b/pi_256b)^N. Also they predate IEEE FP so you have to reoptimise them to get something decent. The preliminary coefficients below are pretty good and should yield the histograms (I still expect to be able to make slight improvements though). I've also rescaled them for direct comparison with Chux's solution. Finding the true global optimum is remarkably difficult. This is the best that I have so far using a 3,4 polynomial and Cody-White evaluation.

| Poly | 0 (1) | 1 (x^2) | 2 (x^4) | 3 (x^6) | 4 (x^8) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Pn | 13863796.6635676 | -1849201.71988148 | 47481.9479832591 | -247.631071978277 | 0 |
| Qn | 13863796.6635676 | -6470467.27440402 | 355798.150975585 | -4322.94411363202 | 6.90686470740337 |
| Pn CW | 0 | 4621265.55452254 | -308316.202992326 | 4075.31304165375 | -6.90686470740337 |
| Pn norm | 1 | -0.133383499827357 | 3.42488779484454E-03 | -1.78617068605039E-05 | 0 |
| Qn norm | 1 | -0.466716833160691 | 2.56638321817414E-02 | -3.118153142704550E-04 | 4.981943168247540E-07 |

Computed the obvious way as the ratio of the two polynomials the resulting histogram is strikingly similar to the one I posted in my question. It gets interesting when we use the C-W form with the best approximation I have been able to refine coming in at 75% in the zero error bin:

```
-3.3307e-16 | 0
-2.2204e-16 | 176464459
-1.1102e-16 | 0
 0.0000e+00 | 750213762
 1.1102e-16 | 64459601
 2.2204e-16 | 8294911
 3.3307e-16 | 567250
 4.4409e-16 | 17
 5.5511e-16 | 0

 Mean  -2.99957e-17   StdDev  9.52211e-17  Entropy 0.742431
```

The mean value is a bit off but that seems to be a part of the price for tightening in the histogram distribution. Recomputing my original 3,3 approximation in C_W form also improves its accuracy at the expense of one more multiply. The corresponding histogram for the original coefficients with evaluation in C-W form is below.

```
-3.3307e-16 | 0
-2.2204e-16 | 135329031
-1.1102e-16 | 0
 0.0000e+00 | 553769720
 1.1102e-16 | 295299243
 2.2204e-16 | 15601028
 3.3307e-16 | 978
 4.4409e-16 | 0

 Mean  6.20017e-18   StdDev  1.05085e-16 Entropy 1.02306
```

It's mean is significantly better. I'm not sure why. Luck perhaps? I think I will just have to live with a few outliers one of these two now looks accurate and should be fast enough. Thanks everyone for your help and I'm still interested in any other suggestions to improve accuracy (or speed) further.

This is operating in a regime where the rounding errors are playing their part in exactly what happens so that how you normalise the coefficients rearranges the error curve but mostly keeps the histogram looking similar. Final polynomial will have one of the terms in x^2n rescaled to unity to save a multiply (I'm less sure about this now). An extra multiply may be the price for best accuracy.

Over the holidays I got the ARM remez exchange code working properly and obtained two new candidate sets of coefficients and here is a sample routine with them which just meets my original target on the Intel 2023 compiler. Ironically the more easily obtained expression for the even function tan(x)/x though less accurate was the winner but this may be because I haven't found the right set of 64bit rounded coefficients for the direct tan(x) odd function approximation yet.

```
double TanPQ(double x)
{
   const double P[4] = { 1.00000000000000002101692511410, 
   -0.12828404846419426254019165401794, 0.0028059826439941866, -7.48425853886355e-06 };
   const double Q[4] = { 1.0,                          
   -0.4616173817975245290363098913219043583, 0.0233451099097620, -0.00020845728971555 };
   // derived from tan(x+1e-200)/(x+1e-200) & remezEven minimax error 2.117e-17 (coeffs good to ~38 decimal digits) - tweaked for Intel compiler
   //
   //   const double P[4] = { 1.000000000000000152554078967622,
   // -0.1282895934385853101554973827882, 0.002806600550621594958697, -7.490248838823649e-06 };
   //   const double Q[4] = { 1.0, 
   //   -0.4616229267719100865648339040111, 
   //   0.02334757614111902357300837,-0.00020854602688336556432};
   // derived from tan(x) & remezOdd minimax error 8.327e-18 (coeffs good to ~40 decimal digits) - untweaked
   // previous best from another algorithm reserved below
   //   const double P[4] = { 1.00000000000000022221943362790, -0.12829413531704511253799276064,
   // 0.0028071066076690946649058, -7.4951506547681147250e-6 };
   //   const double Q[4] = { 1.0, 
   // -0.461627468650366656307298511378729, 0.0233495961576097899048136377, -0.00020861868350387521217199289 };
  double sumP, sumQ, x2;
  int i;
  sumP = sumQ = 0;
  x2 = x * x;
  for (i = 3; i >= 0; i--)
  {
     sumP = sumP * x2 + P[i];
     sumQ = sumQ * x2 + Q[i];
  }
  return x * sumP / sumQ;
}
```

Intel compiler with SSE2 or AVX2 will use FMA code for polynomials and so obtains very high accuracy. Have seen 3 fails >2.2e-16 in ~10^11 random tests. Sample histogram below:

```
Random challenge test 1000000000 x 239 : Ver tanPQ
        Error              x
-2.220446e-16      0.09765394018257756
+2.220446e-16      -0.1631142173020804

-3.3307e-16 | 0
-2.2204e-16 | 174282938
-1.1102e-16 | 0
 0.0000e+00 | 719208231
 1.1102e-16 | 67588751
 2.2204e-16 | 38920080
 3.3307e-16 | 0

 Mean  -2.25527e-17   StdDev  1.04097e-16   Entropy 0.849989
```

I reckon that Intel's LLL code for optimising the coefficients could do better. Does anybody have access to it? There is headroom remaining for improving the accuracy of the rounded coefficients.

Good news I have a 7,6 rational that is good enough. Bad news is that it only works as normal C code on the Intel compiler. MSC and GCC will require explicit FMA coding to reach target accuracy.

Comment: Arg!! The x^8 coefficients looked fine in preview mode but have been truncated in the final form.  Should read 6.90686470740337 and 4.981943168247540E-07 respectively.

Comment: Re "... the count in the 5.5e-16 bin". I am confused. Why are the bins not stated in ulps? I assume you are aware that relative error and ulp error cannot be used interchangeably (ulp error is basically scaled absolute error with scale dependent on binade).

Comment: @njuffa Mainly because I'm actually binning on relative error rather than ULP because I think it is faster.

Comment: It is likely true that computing relative error is slightly faster than computing ulp error, but the difference is noise compared to the cost of computing the reference. If the goal is a 1 ulp error bound, a methodology that tracks relative error does not seem to generate relevant data. One might distinguish instead (and I have used this in practice in addition to tracking maximum ulp error: (1) percentage of correctly rounded results, error <= 0.5 ulp (2) percentage of results that are faithfully rounded, error <= 1 ulp, (3) percentage of results with errors larger than 1 ulp.